# Datamapper datetime property

Tags: ruby, datetime, sqlite, datamapper

I got stuck with some strange behavior of DataMapper's DateTime property.

Here's a simple code:

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, 'sqlite::/path/to/some/file.db')

class Event
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :time, DateTime

end
```

I create one item:

```
e = Event.new
e.time = Time.now
e.save
```

And now strange things happen:
Time before save is ok.
In the database file time is also ok.

```
puts e.time.to_s 
# 2011-05-01T22:38:49+02:00
```

But then I'm getting DateTime without "time" part.

```
puts Event.first.time.to_s 
# 2011-05-01T00:00:00+02:00
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you've hit a bug in latest DataObjects. It will be fixed in next version, there's already a pull request that fixes the bug: https://github.com/datamapper/do/pull/9